# Euler's Formula for Primes

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-fields

Is there any way to prove that the Euler's Formula for Primes $n^2+n+41=41^2$ is valid? How would you even start to prove that a number is prime? If you could prove that a certain number is prime, it maybe possible to do a proof by induction, but since n is limited to $[-40,40)$, induction should theoretically fail (unless you do a modulo 41 <-- oh wait does that give any ideas? except that it's the value of $k=41$). I really don't even know where to start...

Comment: The formula is:

$$P(n) = n^2 - n + 41$$

Comment: There are only 40 values, you plug them in and check, that they are prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Euler's Prime Generating Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html) is the polynomial $$f(n):=n^2-n+41.$$  It has a pretty property that $f(n)$ is prime for $-39 \leq n \leq 40$.

Of course, $f(41)$ is divisible by $41$, as will be $f(n)$ for any $n \equiv 0 \pmod {41}$.  Except for when $n=0$, these cases will all be composite (since $41$ will be a proper divisor).  We also observe that other composites arise, such as $f(42)=1763=41 \times 43$ and $f(45)=43 \times 47$.

Calling it a *prime generating polynomial* is somewhat misleading: it "generates" infinitely many composites too.

It will therefore not be possible to prove by induction that it generates primes, since it doesn't generate primes for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: So basically, there is no way to prove it, except by testing all the possible cases described by euler and finding that there are no counter-examples?

Comment: Well, to check that it's prime for $-39 \leq n \leq 40$, there's probably no better method than to just check the numbers for primality individually.  Euler had access to a table of small primes, so he could just look the numbers up in the table.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple conceptual explanation for the fact that $p(n)$ is prime
for $-40 < n < 41$, where $p(n) = n^2-n+1$.

First one needs to know that the ring of integers $A = Z + Z\tau$, where $\tau = (1+\sqrt{-163})/2$ is a root of $p(n)$, is a unique factorization domain.  (For this it suffices to check that $p(n)$ has no root mod $p$ for $p=2,3,5,7$,  which just means we first check that $p(n)$ is prime for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$.)

To connect $\tau$ and $p(n)$, we note that the norm $N(a) = |a|^2$ on $A$
satisfies $N(\tau-n) = p(n)$.

Next, observe that $\tau$ minimizes the norm $N(a)$ and
$|\Im(a)|$ over all $a$ in $A-Z$.

Now suppose $\tau-n$ factors nontrivially as $ab$ in $A$.  Then neither $a$ nor $b$ lies in $Z$, by the observation on imaginary parts.  Thus $N(\tau -n) \ge N(a)N(b) \ge 41^2$.

Put differently, this shows that $\tau-n$ is a prime in $A$ provided $p(n) < 41^2 = 1681$, which is exactly the range $-40 < n < 41$.  It follows that $N(\tau-n) = p(n) = q$ or $q^2$ for some ordinary prime $q$ in $Z$.  The second case can only occur when $q$ is an associate of $\tau-n$, which is impossible since the only units in $A$ are $\pm 1$.  Thus $p(n)=q$ is prime.